# Error 403 – Forbidden SAP when accessing HANA Web-Based Development Workbench

Tags: hana, sap-cloud-platform

SAP HANA experts.

I have created a HANA database in my SAP Cloud Platform account for a Neo environment.

When I clicked SAP HANA Web-Based Development Workbench and provided the credentials of the SYSTEM user, I saw the screen with error 403 - Forbidden. I follow all the steps like in this blog: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/24/create-a-hana-mdc-and-access-the-sap-web-based-development-workbench/

I read that I must login to SAP HANA Cockpit and assign the correct roles, but I can't access SAP HANA Cockpit because the link doesn't appear.

Any idea what goes wrong?

These are the screenshots:

- HANA Overview 
  [image]
- 403 Forbidden 
  [image]

Comment: Hi aimee, you are in neo environment or cloud foundry?  Because my ui is a little bit different

Comment: Hi, Ivan. I'm in the Neo environment.

Comment: You are owner of the subaccount?, i think you can't see the links because you need permissions. Please go to permissions tab and check if your user is there, not the SYSTEM user,  just your S-USER. If you think all is right there, please go to you idp settings and check if yours permissions are ok. The permission names something like *hana* (Right now i don't remember the permission names) and the last part is to check at subaccount level.